# light mode, tezos-client. how does it work?

Tags: tezos-client

I skimmed the docs here: https://tezos.gitlab.io/user/light.html

but was hoping for an ELI5/tl;dr example on how to use tezos-client light mode

Comment: There are usage examples in the doc page you cite. What's wrong about them?

Comment: i don't understand it. can you use light mode to tezos-client transfer without the chain being synced locally?

Comment: In the default (aka. client) mode, the client queries a single node, the node stores the data and performs most of the computations. In mockup mode, the client talks to no node, it stores all data and performs all computations locally. In proxy mode, the client talks to a single node that stores the data but the client performs the computation locally. In light mode, the client talks to several nodes, each node stores all data, the client check that they give the same answer, and the client still performs computations locally.

Comment: So the only mode that requires data to be stored client side is mockup mode.